# Slow focusing input fields in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a big data table with 2-cols where storing input fields (`type="text"`), there is no events, but only the HTML and CSS focus and hover properties, so here is the HTML:

```
            <tr <?=($pKey%2!=0)?'style="background-color:#eee;"':''?>>
               <td>
 Some data: 
               </td>
               <td>
 Some data: 
               </td>               
               <td width="200">
                  <input type="hidden" name="cyber_id[]" value="<?=$pVal?>"/>

                  <input name="bank_commission[]" type="text" class="bank_commission" value=""/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input name="bank_reward[]" type="text" class="bank_reward" value=""/>          
               </td>               
            </tr>
```

CSS for every field:

```
input {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    font: normal 14px Tahoma;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /*behavior: url(/style/PIE.php);*/
    padding: 3px;
    color: #555;
    outline: 0 none;
}

input:hover {
    border: 1px solid #0075BB;
    font: normal 14px Tahoma;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /*behavior: url(/style/PIE.php);*/
    padding: 3px;
    outline: 0 none;
}
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #0075BB;
}
```

The exact issue is that when I'm clicking on the field the cursor shows after 2-4 seconds past, this can't be good for users.
There is no CSS for either `bank_commission` nor `bank_reward`, so this is not a point.

Comment: can you elaborate what issue are you exactly facing...is it that chrome is slower in focusing the input elements?

Comment: As I'd edited the question: The exact issue is that when I'm clicking on the field the cursor shows after 2-4 seconds past, this can't be good for users.

Comment: Also if that would be helpfull, there is a 5608 rows, that equals 11216 fields loading on the page. In FF everything is cool, Safari behaves as Chrome, but after loading the page and more a little while acts faster. Seems like core can't handle this data massive.

Answer (score 0):

too much of form elements and that too in a table will definitely hog the browser...why don't you try showing the data in chunks....say in chunks of 100 rows and add lazy loading to load the next chunk of data...and also if you convert your table layout into div layout then it will also make the page lighter.